# Mongo DB find by field name with any value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find all documents that have this field, it doesn't matter what exact value it contains; I am only interested in the existence of it.

Here is an example:

```
{  
   "payload":{  
      "products":{  
         ...
      },
      "discount":{  
         "type":"1%",
         "value":"1",
         "name":"New Year Discount 1%"
      }
   }
}
```

I need to target any document that has a field with the name `discount`. How can I write a query to get such documents?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's a [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator for that:

```
db.collectionName.find({"payload.discount": {$exists: true}})
```

Answer (score 12):

You're probably looking for the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```
db.collection.find({ "payload.discount": { $exists: true } })
```