# How to query all the documents in collection with Map dynamically generated key?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My Tests collection is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da6a06ebd122e45c4533b64"), "attributesMap" : { "key1" : { "attr1" : "val1", "attr2" : "val2" } }, "name" : "Test Name", "test" : "Simple test data", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da6a06ebd122e45c4533b65"), "attributesMap" : { "key1" : { "attr1" : "val1", "attr2" : "val2" } }, "name" : "Test Name", "test" : "Simple test data", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da6a06ebd122e45c4533b66"), "attributesMap" : { "key1" : { "attr1" : "val1", "attr2" : "val2" } }, "name" : "Test Name", "test" : "Simple test data", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da6a06ebd122e45c4533b67"), "attributesMap" : { "key1" : { "attr1" : "val1", "attr2" : "val2" } }, "name" : "Test Name", "test" : "Simple test data", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da6a06ebd122e45c4533b68"), "attributesMap" : { "key1" : { "attr1" : "val1", "attr2" : "val2" } }, "name" : "Test Name", "test" : "Simple test data", "__v" : 0 }
```

I can easily query documents using top-level parameters but for nested params, e.g. I want to query all the documents whos `attributesMap` has a subkey `key1` ?

For the above sample collection data answer for `key1` will be 5 documents & for `key2` it would be 0 documents.

Note: `attributesMap` is `Map` type. I can't find use cases related to Map in any example.

***Update***

Most people suggested this could be possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738086/mongo-db-find-by-field-name-with-any-value) question

But when I tried:

```
TestData.find( {  'attributesMap.key1' : { $exists: true } }, ( err: Error, res: ITestData[] ) => {
            if ( err ) console.log( 'err.message ' + err.message );
            if ( res ) console.log( 'res.length ' + res.length );
            if ( res ) {
                res.forEach( element => {
                    console.log( 'Element: ' + JSON.stringify( element ) );
                } );
            }
        } );
```

I am getting the `5` results, but how do I dynamically construct `'attributesMap.key1'`? One possible solution could have been a string like below:

```
const key = 'key1';
const expr = "attributesMap." + key;
        TestData.find( {  expr : { $exists: true } }, ( err: Error, res: ITestData[] ) => {
....
});
```

But the `const expr = "attributesMap." + key;` value is not passed to find's condition section the `expr` param is treated as new variable here & results after this change are `0`

***Solution***

In comments section User [sushant-mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7727285/sushant-mehta) & [Ashh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/ashh) solved the problem of dynamic condition definition.

1] Approach by sushant-mehta

```
const key = 'key1'; let expr = "attributesMap." + key; let expr2={};
expr2[expr]={'$exists': true};
TestData.find( expr2, ( err: Error, res: ITestData[] ) => {
...
});
```

2] Approach by Assh

```
TestData.find( TestData.find({ ['attributesMap.' + keyName] : { $exists: true } }), ( err: Error, res: ITestData[] ) => {
    ...
    });
```

Both are working.

Comment: in query use $exists as "attributesMap.key1":{$exists:true} & "attributesMap.key2":{$exists:true}

Comment: @sushantmehta please take a look at the updated question, Thanks for reply

Comment: try 
const key = 'key1';
let expr = "attributesMap." + key;
let expr2={}
expr2[expr]={"exists":true}
and pass expr2 in query

Comment: `TestData.find({ ['attributesMap.' + keyName] : { $exists: true } })`