# findOne document without a particular element

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
text = {
    name : String,
    text: String,
    class: String (optional)
}
```

how can i findOne that do not have a class yet?

i was hoping for something like this:

```
text.findOne({
    class: null
})
.then(text => res.json(text))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738086/mongo-db-find-by-field-name-with-any-value/47738123#47738123 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
text.findOne({
    "class" : { "$exists" : false } 
}).then(text => res.json(text))
```